# サーバーに送られたデータがメモリ上からストレージ上に書き込まれるタイミング

Tags: database, ハードウェア

コンピュータの構成と設計を勉強しています。

コンピュータは主記憶と補助記憶があり、それぞれSRAM&DRAM, 磁気ディスクで構成されており、
主記憶は電気系なので高速アクセスできるが、シャットダウンすればデータ保持ができない。
補助記憶は機械系なので低速だが、磁気ディスクにデータを書き込みデータ保存ができる。
という認識であっていますか？

複数のユーザーがデータ管理のためにリモートで利用するようなサーバにおいて、
ユーザーがデータを送信すると、サーバー上で動いているアプリケーションが受け取ったデータは
どのようにデータベースに保存されますか？

まず主記憶に保存されて、タイミングを見て補助記憶に保存するような場合はありますか？

Answer (score 0):

補助記憶装置に書き込まれるべきデータは、まずメインメモリ上でバッファリングされ、然るべき後、ある程度まとめて補助記憶装置に書き込まれます
これはデータベースに限らず、一般的なOS上でのデータの振る舞いとしては常識的な動作となっています